# file_put_contents() or similar to create new photo

Tags: php

I receive a string of base64 and am able to decode it and put it into a file. The problem is, I would like to create a new image file each time to put this base64 into.

Currently I have a basic code which is able to put contents into the file that is pre-existing but the current code does not create a non-existent file.

```
$data = base64_decode($data);

$path = 'abc';

var_dump(is_dir($path));

if ( ! is_dir($path)) {
    if(mkdir($path, 0777)) {
      echo "created dir";
    }
}

file_put_contents('tmp.png', $data);
```

Comment: Why are you creating a directory but not putting the file in it?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` will create a file if you have permission to write to the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base64 function to decode

```
function base64ToFile($base64String, $outputFile) {
    $file = fopen($outputFile, "wb");
    $data = explode(',', $base64String);
    fwrite($file, base64_decode($data[1]));
    fclose($file);

    return $outputFile;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this will work when `file_put_contents()` fails?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` successively to write data to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Check this the function will return you the unique name after uploading your image in a directory

```
$imageBase64=$_POST['image_converted_base64'];//get base64 of image from client end

 $unique_name =uploadSingleImage($imageBase64);//function call

//function to upload image and get an unique name to store in db

    function uploadSingleImage($base64) {

        $uniname = uniqid() . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . ".png";
        $new_image_url = "../../image/" . $uniname;
        $base64 = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $base64;
        $base64 = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/\w+;base64,#i', '', $base64));
        file_put_contents($new_image_url, $base64);
        return $uniname;
    }
```

Comment: I am getting 'Warning: file_put_contents(image/5d2888df9d6012019-07-12-13-19-27.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/api/v1/kyle/index.php on line 20"

Comment: You have to create the directory image and give the write permission to the directory in which you want to upload image

Comment: I'm giving an uptick for the base64 preg conversion. ta.